# Responsive Web Design: How to get header image to be fully responsive when re-sizing window browser?

Tags: css, html, image, responsive-design, responsive

I'm using media queries to properly align the header image to the container div underneath it. It looks great when in large desktop or mobile mode, however when I re-size to other sizes and change browser window it moves. Should I be setting more breakpoints and more specific ones for the media queries? I've tried also placing it as a background-image: cover but that does not seem to work either.

Comment: 1.make use of units like vw and vh.
[link](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) 

2. make use of `@media` query
[link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

Comment: There is at least one error: `class=".img-responsive"` should be `class="img-responsive"`